# Coproducts in $\mathbf{Grp}$ and in $\mathbf{Ab}$

Tags: category-theory

In the category $\mathbf{Ab}$ of abelian groups the coproduct of two groups is the direct sum $A\oplus B$, which is the same as the cartesian product $A\times B$.

I wonder if this is also true in the category $\mathbf{Grp}$ of groups. So: Let $A,B$ be two abelian groups. Is $A\times B$ in general a coproduct product in $\mathbf{Grp}$?

Searching lead to the answer *no*.

Has anybody a counter-example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the category of groups, the coproduct is the free product of groups. For example, $A = B = \mathbb Z$ has $F_2$ (free group on $2$ generators) as coproduct and $\mathbb Z^2$ as product.

Comment: It might be worth noting that coproduct in $\bf{Ab}$ is $\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z$ which is free _abelian_ group on $2$ generators. This is not coincidence, since $\Bbb Z$ is free group over $1$ generator, and free objects commute with coproducts. Thus, coproduct of any number of copies of $\Bbb Z$ must be free object on that same number of generators. That is why we get different coproducts in $\bf{Grp}$ and $\bf{Ab}$, since construction of free objects is not same.

Comment: Without knowing the fact that the coproduct is the free product: Can one somehow prove that $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is not a coproduct in the category of groups?

Comment: @user114179, yes. Just write down appropriate diagram for coproduct and show that $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ does not satisfy the universal property by finding counterexample.

Comment: Yep this is what I have done so far, but I didn't find a counterexample. Which group and which maps should I look at?

Comment: if you take just about any group $\notin Ab$, you can show the coproduct in $Ab$ does not satisfy the universal property in $Grp$.

Comment: So which group is the easiest to take?

Comment: @user114179, start by writing down any group $G$. You can easily describe what universal map $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to G$ should look like (well, the same as in abelian case). Obviously, trouble will be with nonabelian group $G$. More concretely universal map won't be homomorphism at all if you have $x,y\in G$ such that $xy\neq yx$.

Comment: An easy example could be to take your favourite nonabelian group $G$ and fix $x, y \in G$ such that $xy \neq yx$. Now, consider the maps $\Bbb Z \to G$ defined by $1 \mapsto x$ and $1 \mapsto y$. Looking at the image of $(1, 1)$ now gives a problem.